# Dash in the bibliography for a custom entry type/field

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I has created a custom entry type for manage the registers of an archive where the *jurisdiction* is the lead element of the reference, and not an author. And I would like to configure the `DeclareBibliographyDriver` (using `biblatex`) to add the dash for references that have the same *jurisdiction*.

So, in my case, the bib file `references.bib` have the next entries (where `@register` is the custom entry type)

```
@register{refacteID312,
  jurisdiction = {Biarritz, Pyrénées Atlantiques, France},
  volume = {Etat Civil, Collection communale, Marriages (1843-1852)},
  section = {Section 1845},
  repository = {Archives Départementales des Pyrénées Atlantiques},
  repositorylocation = {Bayonne},  
}

@register{refacteID313,
  jurisdiction = {Biarritz, Pyrénées Atlantiques, France},
  volume = {Etat Civil, Collection communale, Marriages (1853-1862)},
  section = {Section 1845},
  repository = {Archives Départementales des Pyrénées Atlantiques},
  repositorylocation = {Bayonne},  
}

@book{negretoponymie1996,
    title = {Toponymie générale de la {France}},
    volume = {2},
    publisher = {Librairie Droz},
    author = {Nègre, Ernest},
    year = {1996},
}
```

The bibliography's output is like that:

[image]

And I would like to have something like that:

[image]

The datamodel file **`evidence.dbx`** with the entry type **`@register`** definition have the next content:

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{register}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  jurisdiction,
  volume,
  section,
  repository,
  repositorylocation,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[register]{
  jurisdiction,
  volume,
  section,
  repository,
  repositorylocation,
}
```

The tex file with the example have the next content :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[datamodel=evidence,backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Lib1.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{jurisdiction}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{volume}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{section}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{repository}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{repositorylocation}{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{register}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{jurisdiction}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{section}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{repository}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{repositorylocation}%   
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography[title={Referencias}]
\end{document}
```

How can I improve this body in order to put the dashes in the bibliography entries that have the same jurisdiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex` has everything built in to handle replacing name lists with dashes, but not literal fields. So we need to recreate what `biblatex` does for names for simple literal fields. A caveat of the straightforward solution shown here is that the dash check for literal fields does not interface with the dash check for name fields, so you won't get a dash if the `author` of a `@book` and the `jurisdiction` of a `@register` are the same.

The idea is to save the last `jurisdiction` with `\savefield` and compare it in the next entry with `\iffieldequals`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{evidence.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{register}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  jurisdiction,
  volume,
  section,
  repository,
  repositorylocation,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[register]{
  jurisdiction,
  volume,
  section,
  repository,
  repositorylocation,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[datamodel=evidence,backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{jurisdiction}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{volume}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{section}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{repository}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[register]{repositorylocation}{#1}

\makeatletter
\InitializeBibliographyStyle{\global\undef\bbx@last@jurisdiction}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck:jurisdiction}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{jurisdiction}\bbx@last@jurisdiction}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:save:jurisdiction}{%
  \savefield{jurisdiction}{\bbx@last@jurisdiction}}%

\newbibmacro{jurisdiction}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck:jurisdiction}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:save:jurisdiction}%
     \printfield{jurisdiction}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{register}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{jurisdiction}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{section}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{repository}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{repositorylocation}%   
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@register{refacteID312,
  jurisdiction       = {Biarritz, Pyrénées Atlantiques, France},
  volume             = {Etat Civil, Collection communale, Marriages (1843-1852)},
  section            = {Section 1845},
  repository         = {Archives Départementales des Pyrénées Atlantiques},
  repositorylocation = {Bayonne},  
}
@register{refacteID313,
  jurisdiction       = {Biarritz, Pyrénées Atlantiques, France},
  volume             = {Etat Civil, Collection communale, Marriages (1853-1862)},
  section            = {Section 1845},
  repository         = {Archives Départementales des Pyrénées Atlantiques},
  repositorylocation = {Bayonne},  
}
@book{negretoponymie1996,
  title     = {Toponymie générale de la {France}},
  volume    = {2},
  publisher = {Librairie Droz},
  author    = {Nègre, Ernest},
  year      = {1996},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography[title={Referencias}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Reference with dash.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and efficient response. I am new to this community and just learning Latex despite comments that I have seen that this technology is outdated. This community and the quality of your response show the opposite. Thank you!